# How to read Doubles from a csv-file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, double

my problem is, that I can't read doubles from the csv-file, but only integers. and so there is the error "-infinity" and "NaN" when I try to make calculations with the growth arrays:

```
    require 'csv'
    filename = 'file.csv'

    csv_data = CSV.read(filename, :col_sep => ";")
    csv_data.shift
    price1, price2 = csv_data.transpose.map { |a| a.map(&:to_i)}


    #calulate yields
    yields1 = Array.new
    yields2 = Array.new

    price1.each_cons(2) { |c| 
    yields1.push(Math.log(c[1]/c[0]))
     }

    price2.each_cons(2) { |c| 
    yields2.push(Math.log(c[1]/c[0]))
     }

    # Statistics

    module Enumerable

     def mean
      mean = self.reduce(:+)/self.length.to_f
      return mean
     end
    end

    puts "mean yields1 = " + yields1.mean.to_s
```

My two Questions:

1. How can I read Doubles from the CSV-file?
2. where is the mistake for the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
price1, price2 = csv_data.transpose.map { |a| a.map(&:to_i)}
```

to

```
price1, price2 = csv_data.transpose.map { |a| a.map(&:to_f)}
```